# Ver mis imágenes de localhost en la web

Tags: php, wordpress, xampp

mi pregunta es si es posible ver las imágenes de mi página de wordpress que esta en un localhost con xampp y lo dirige con un nombre de no-ip, la verdad de código apenas soy novato, pero no eh encontrado una manera de publicar mi sitio y se puedan visualizar las imágenes de este desde otra pc remota, solo se ve la página sin ninguna imágen.

Comment: Hola JuanK, te recomiendo revisar [ask] para que tus preguntas sean bien recibidas por la comunidad y obtengas respuestas de calidad

Comment: lo que entiendo es que publicaste tu sitio a través de un DDNS gratuito y que al acceder desde otra PC a tu sitio, las imágenes no se ven, el problema no está relacionado con el DNS, si no más bien con las rutas de las imágenes, debes verificar que las rutas estén bien, trata de sustituir rutas absolutas por relativas y verifica que los directorios donde las imágenes están, sean accesibles y tengan los permisos adecuados. Saludos espero haya podido apoyarte :) ...

Comment: Muy cierto tu respuesta, pero también es cierto que no tengo mucha experiencia técnica, como puedo proceder? Jaja

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Por lo general wordpress responde bien a especificarle la URL donde está instalado con las siguientes directivas en el wp-config.php

```
define('WP_HOME','http://example.com');
define('WP_SITEURL','http://example.com');
```

ahi cambiarías el http://localhost por la url que te asigna el DDNS

Aunque, hay plugins, themes que pueden buscar la URL con :

```
$home = get_option('home');
```

lo cual es leído desde la DB (define WP_HOME no cambia la DB)

Para pruebas puede funcionar la mayoria de los casos, alternativamente podes cambiar la db desde el functions.php pero no suele ser necesario.

Para cambiar url's dentro de los posts lo mejor es manejarse con WP-cli 
http://wp-cli.org/

```
$ wp search-replace 'example.dev' 'example.com' --skip-columns=guid
```

Mas info:
https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_The_Site_URL

Comment: Muchísimas gracias funcionó al 100!