# Migrar multisite o multisitio de wordpress a local bajo wampserver

Tags: wordpress, webservice, web, wamp

No tengo donde mas buscar ya llevo 2 dias y he hecho todo lo posible pero nada funciona como quiero. Se me asigno un proyecto donde debo migrar una pagina hecha en wordpress multisitio a local para trabajarla.

Pasa lo siguiente, mi jefe me paso los archivos alojados del hosting hasta el sql. Decidí iniciar por un camino rápido donde instale un plugin llamado *duplicator* cual no soporta multisitio al ver esto, decidí hacerlo manual lo cual se me ha hecho muy complicado pero lo dictare por partes:

- Utilizo como Wampserver 3.1.3
- Creo la carpeta dentro de www llamada "prueba"
- copio y pego todos los archivos, incluyendo el .htaccess
- Se importa el archivo .sql que estaba en el hosting

Errores Solucionados:

1. > Internal Server

   La manera de solucionarlo fue eliminando el archivo .htaccess alojado en mi carpeta "prueba"
2. > No Establece coneccion a la base de datos

   Se decide configurar el wp-config cual fue de la siguiente manera:

   **// ** MySQL settings - You can get this info from your web host ** //**

   ```
   define('DB_NAME', 'salem');
   define('DB_USER', 'root');
   define('DB_PASSWORD', '');
   define('DB_HOST', 'localhost');
   define('DB_CHARSET', 'utf8mb4');
   define('DB_COLLATE', '');
   ```

   **/* Multisite */**

   ```
   define( 'WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true );
   define('MULTISITE', true);
   define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
   define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'localhost');
   define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
   define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
   define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
   ```

   En este se puede observar que el Domian cual estaba asociada la pagina ahora es localhost y se usa la cuenta por defecto que viene en phpmyadmin
3. > Configuracion de tablas en phpmyadmin

   Aquí se configuraron las siguientes tablas:

   3.1. *wp-options*: donde se cambio **site_url y home por (http:)localhost/prueba**
   3.2. *wp-blog*: donde se cambio **domain por localhost y el patch por /prueba/**
   3.3. *wp_site*: donde se cambio **domain por localhost y patch por /prueba/**
   3.5. *wp_sitemeta*: donde se cambio siteurl por (http:)localhost/prueba/

Hasta aquí todo bien, observe que me levanto localhost o el contenido de wordpress pero pasa otro problema ya que la pagina no me carga los *stylos* por ningún lado o no se si es el wordpress pero aparece algo como la siguiente imagen

[image: Prueba]

Quiero indicarles que edite el archivo httpd.conf de wampserver, diciendo Allow From all ya que antes de que apareciera asi no tenia permisos y bueno eso es lo que tengo si quieren hagan al prueba o si encuentran una solucion viable seria de mucha ayuda.

Gracias

Comment: fijate los pasos de https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151372/81450 pero al revés (poner localhost) si no resuelve habría que ver cómo carga el theme los estilos (via `header.php` o `functions.php`)

Comment: Listo ya lo resolvi, paso la solucion fue cambiar en las tablas wp-options, wp-site y wp-sitemeta (http:)localhost/prueba por http://localhost/prueba y .htaccess RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /prueba/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L] y cambie de servidor opte por usar Xampp de verdad me fue de maravilla espero que ayude a otros