# Al acceder a través de mi dominio a mi servidor local con wordpress, la url cambia por la IP del servidor

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, apache, dominio

tengo instalado en mi raspberry un servidor web junto con mysql y wordpress corriendo. Compré un dominio con el que acceder a la IP pública de mi servidor de una forma más cómoda. Todo bien, pero a la hora de entrar en esta, en el navegador, en vez de aparecer el nombre de mi dominio que he ingresado para acceder a la web, este se sustituye por mi dirección IP seguido del puerto al que pertenece el servidor.

Aquí viene la cuestión, ¿cómo he de hacer para que al acceder a mi wordpress a través de mi dominio, la url al entrar no cambie por: 123.456.789.321:8800(ejemplo) ?

=

¿Como evito que aparezca mi ip en el navegador al entrar por el dominio?

Espero que me puedan ayudar, si necesitáis algún dato hacérmelo saber.

Comment: wordpress tiene la url de instalación guardada en la db, podés decirle que la cambie con unas options en el wp-config.php fijate si esta respuesta te sirve: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151372/81450

Comment: Esto lo había intentado, pero no hacía nada. Ten en cuenta que wordpress está instalado en un servidor local accesible desde el exterior. Por lo que la instalación de wordpress está bajo la IPPUBLICA:8800 o IPLOCAL:8800 por lo que se vería así nada mas acceder desde mi dominio midominio.es -----> 123.456.789.321:8800/index.php

Comment: Posible duplicado de [Ver mis imágenes de localhost en la web](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/151356/ver-mis-im%c3%a1genes-de-localhost-en-la-web)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

prueba de entrar a `tudominio.com/wp-admin/options.php` y modificar los campos `home` y `siteurl` por tu dominio.

A parte, en el archivo `wp-config.php`, prueba de añadir estas dos líneas sustituyendo tu url por tu dominio.

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'tuurl' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'tuurl' );
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda, un saludo

Comment: Sí, el problema lo tenia en que la url que introducía en wp-config.php, no saltaba directamente a mi servidor.