# Get_template_directory_uri() wordpress retorna ruta local en remoto

Tags: php, wordpress

Acabo de desplegar un proyecto de wordpress desarrollado en local a un entorno remoto. Dominio y hosting de hostalia.
El problema que tengo es que la función get_template_directory_uri() sigue tomando el localhost:10008 y no el nuevo dominio, por lo que no coge mi hoja de estilos y muchos redireccionamientos fallan.
Alguien sabe por qué ocurre esto??

Comment: varias funciones toman el home/root desde la db fijate por ejemplo https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151372/81450

Comment: Modificaste la ruta en la base de datos, o como hiciste para migrar de local a online? para verificar ve a tu base de datos e ingresa a la tabla wp_options, verifica desde ahi que el siteurl y el home en option_value esten apuntando a tu dominio en producción, no al localhost

Comment: correcto, he modificado la tabla de wp-options y ya puedo acceder a la home de forma correcta.
Después, he tenido problema con el menú, porque todos los enlaces me decían que la página a la que quería ir no existía... He entrado como administrador para ver si cada página tenía la url correcta y estaba todo correcto. Al salir de mi perfil, he vuelto a entrar por curiosidad y ya funciona...

Comment: Espero que no vuelva a dar problemas. En cualquier caso, muchas gracias!!

Comment: quiero votar también a @JefferzonBol pero no me deja... Su respuesta es correcta!!

Comment: He agregado la respuesta, si te funciono favor votarla como aceptada, que tengas feliz semana

Comment: hecho amigo!!  Muchas gracias a los dos!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modificaste la ruta en la base de datos, o como hiciste para migrar de local a online? para verificar ve a tu base de datos e ingresa a la tabla wp_options, verifica desde ahí que el siteurl y el home en option_value estén apuntando a tu dominio en producción, no al localhost.

Generalmente suele pasar ya que al importar la base de datos cosas como los enlaces se copian tal cual, al modificar estos enlaces principales wordpress se encarga de actualizar los demás enlaces, a veces no pasa de manera automática, cuando es así siempre puede actualizar los enlaces permanentes de forma manual.