# Cambiar la URL de una página en Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Como puedo adicionar 3 letras al link de mi post?
Por ejemplo:
Tengo un link así:

```
https://sitioweb.com/producto/bebida
```

Quería que en lugar de que aparezca así; apareciese un subdominio, de esta forma

```
https://en.sitioweb.com/producto/bebida
```

Es posible hacer eso en WordPress?

He intentado usar lo siguiente:

```
<?php
$link = get_permalink();
$novo_link = substr($link, 7, -1);
?>
<a href="en.<?= $novo_link;?>"></a>
```

Eso me dá como resultado:

```
https://sitioweb.com/producto/bebida/en.
```

Alguien sabe como consigo que ese "**en.**" vaya al comienzo del link, quedando así?

```
https://en.sitioweb.com/producto/bebida/
```

Comment: si ya tenés configurado el subdominio, cambiale la url al wordpress https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/151372/81450

Comment: Creo que no fui claro @aloMalbarez, deseo colocar ese subdominio de forma dinámica en mi sitio web por eso deseo que ese **en.** aparezca dinamicamente cuando alguien entrar en ciertas páginas. Por ejemplo:
Si un usuario entra en mi sitio normal la url permanece normal https://misitio.com/home pero si el usuario quiere cambiar de idioma se creara un link https://en.misitio.com/home para que el usuario lo vea en ingles.